# ProgressDialog inside AsyncTask include UI load

Tags: java, android-asynctask, android-dialog

It's look like a common question, but I didn't find the answer yet after a long search.

My problem is that I tried to receive data from a web service and after I get all the data I need to update the UI with these data.

The difference from what I found is that also the UI takes time (about 5 sec), so in all examples I saw, the data received in doInBackground() and all the UI work done in onPostExecute() and before the UI work done the ProgressDialog is dismissed so it is look like it worked(the ProgressDialog doesn't stuck) but after it disappear I wait more 5 second to the UI appear.

This is part of may code that I tried:

```
 private class RequestResponse extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
    {
        private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        protected String doInBackground(String... uri)
        {
            String response="";
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse httpResponse;
            InputStream content;
            BufferedReader buffer;
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(uri[0]);

            try 
            {

                httpResponse = client.execute(request);
                content = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

                buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));

                String s = "";
                while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) 
                {
                 response += s;
                }
                ProcessResponse(response);//Received data from server

                return response;
            }

             catch (Exception e) 
             {
                response = e.getMessage();
                return response;
             }

        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {}
        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {
            super.onPreExecute();

            this.dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            this.dialog.setMessage("Processing..."); 
            this.dialog.setCancelable(false);
            this.dialog.isIndeterminate();
            this.dialog.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
            this.dialog.show();
           btnSearch.setEnabled(false);
           txtSearch.setEnabled(false);
           isFirstViewClick=false;
           isSecondViewClick=false;
           isThirdViewClick=false;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
        {

           this.dialog.dismiss();
           AddDataToView();// Do UI work
           btnSearch.setEnabled(true);
           txtSearch.setEnabled(true);

        }
    }
```

- I tried also using Progressbar instead of ProgressDialog but the results are the same.

**Update:**
This is the code for Update UI, I'll the most of the code from [this web](http://techlovejump.com/android-multilevel-listview-tutorial/)
   but I added 1 more level. in the site there is no function for this use the just do it in onCreate().

```
    private void AddDataToView()
            {
                //Adds data into first row
                for (int i = 0; i < mainList.size(); i++) 
                {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = null;
                    inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    View mLinearView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_first, null);

                    final TextView mProductName = (TextView) mLinearView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
                    final RelativeLayout mLinearFirstArrow=(RelativeLayout)mLinearView.findViewById(R.id.linearFirst);
                    final ImageView m

ImageArrowFirst=(ImageView)mLinearView.findViewById(R.id.imageFirstArrow);
                final LinearLayout mLinearScrollSecond=(LinearLayout)mLinearView.findViewById(R.id.linear_scroll);

                //checkes if menu is already opened or not
                if(isFirstViewClick==false)
                {
                    mLinearScrollSecond.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mImageArrowFirst.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_lt);
                }
                else
                {
                    mLinearScrollSecond.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mImageArrowFirst.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_down);
                }
                //Handles onclick effect on list item
                mLinearFirstArrow.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        Log.v("Event", "MotionEvent: " + event.getAction());
                        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                        {
                            if(isFirstViewClick==false)
                            {
                                isFirstViewClick=true;
                                mImageArrowFirst.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_down);
                                mLinearScrollSecond.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                isFirstViewClick=false;
                                mImageArrowFirst.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_lt);
                                mLinearScrollSecond.setVisibility(View.GONE);   
                            }
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                });
                final String name = mainList.get(i).getpName();
                mProductName.setText(name);

                //Adds data into second row
                for (int j = 0; j < mainList.get(i).getmRevisionsList().size(); j++) 
                {
                    LayoutInflater inflaterSecond = null;
                    inflaterSecond = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    View mLinearViewSecond = inflaterSecond.inflate(R.layout.row_second, null);

                    TextView mSubItemNameSecond = (TextView) mLinearViewSecond.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
                    final RelativeLayout mLinearSecondArrow=(RelativeLayout)mLinearViewSecond.findViewById(R.id.linearSecond);
                    final ImageView mImageArrowSecond=(ImageView)mLinearViewSecond.findViewById(R.id.imageSecondArrow);
                    final LinearLayout mLinearScrollThird=(LinearLayout)mLinearViewSecond.findViewById(R.id.linear_scroll_third);

                    //checkes if menu is already opened or not
                    if(isSecondViewClick==false)
                    {
                        mLinearScrollThird.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mImageArrowSecond.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_lt);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mLinearScrollThird.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mImageArrowSecond.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_down);
                    }
                    //Handles onclick effect on list item   
                    mLinearSecondArrow.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
                    {   
                            @Override
                            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
                            {
                                Log.v("Event", "MotionEvent: " + event.getAction());
                                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                                {
                                    if(isSecondViewClick==false)
                                    {
                                        isSecondViewClick=true;
                                        mImageArrowSecond.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_down);
                                        mLinearScrollThird.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        isSecondViewClick=false;
                                        mImageArrowSecond.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_lt);
                                        mLinearScrollThird.setVisibility(View.GONE);    
                                    }
                                }
                                return true;
                            } 
                        });


                    final String RevNum= mainList.get(i).getmRevisionsList().get(j).getpRevisionNumber();
                    mSubItemNameSecond.setText(RevNum);

                    //Adds data into Third row
                    for (int k = 0; k < mainList.get(i).getmRevisionsList().get(j).getmDefinitionsList().size(); k++) 
                    {
                        LayoutInflater inflaterThird = null;
                        inflaterThird = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        View mLinearViewThird = inflaterThird.inflate(R.layout.row_third, null);

                        TextView mSubItemNameThird = (TextView) mLinearViewThird.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
                        final RelativeLayout mLinearThirdArrow=(RelativeLayout)mLinearViewThird.findViewById(R.id.linearThird);
                        final ImageView mImageArrowThird =(ImageView)mLinearViewThird.findViewById(R.id.imageThirdArrow);
                        final LinearLayout mLinearScrollFourth=(LinearLayout)mLinearViewThird.findViewById(R.id.linear_scroll_fourth);

                        //checkes if menu is already opened or not
                        if(isThirdViewClick==false)
                        {
                            mLinearScrollFourth.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            mImageArrowThird.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_lt);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            mLinearScrollFourth.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            mImageArrowThird.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_down);
                        }
                        //Handles onclick effect on list item   
                        mLinearThirdArrow.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
                        {   
                                @Override
                                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
                                {
                                    Log.v("Event", "MotionEvent: " + event.getAction());
                                    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                                    {
                                        if(isThirdViewClick==false)
                                        {
                                            isThirdViewClick=true;
                                            mImageArrowThird.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_down);
                                            mLinearScrollFourth.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            isThirdViewClick=false;
                                            mImageArrowThird.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_lt);
                                            mLinearScrollFourth.setVisibility(View.GONE);   
                                        }
                                    }
                                    return true;
                                } 
                            });


                        final String DefName= mainList.get(i).getmRevisionsList().get(j).getmDefinitionsList().get(k).getpDefinitionName();
                        mSubItemNameThird.setText(DefName);

                        //Adds items in subcategories
                        for (int l = 0; l < mainList.get(i).getmRevisionsList().get(j).getmDefinitionsList().get(k).getmItemArray().size(); l++) 
                        {
                            LayoutInflater inflaterFourth = null;
                            inflaterFourth = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                            View mLinearViewFourth = inflaterFourth.inflate(R.layout.row_fourth, null);

                            TextView mItemNameFourth = (TextView) mLinearViewFourth.findViewById(R.id.textViewItemName);
                            final String itemName = mainList.get(i).getmRevisionsList().get(j).getmDefinitionsList().get(k).getmItemArray().get(l).getItemName();
                            mItemNameFourth.setText(itemName);

                            mLinearScrollFourth.addView(mLinearViewFourth);
                         }
                        mLinearScrollThird.addView(mLinearViewThird);
                    }
                    mLinearScrollSecond.addView(mLinearViewSecond);
                }
                mLinearListView.addView(mLinearView);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Your real problem is that after all the background work is done successfully your UI takes to update about 5 secs? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, there is a lot of work there

Comment: Ithink that the problem caused all the "FindByID()" cause I have a lots of Views to define, according to [THIS](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) site. I tried to do what they said but it didn't work.